# How would I add user input to a list? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm looking to write a function that will prompt the user for a series ages and store them in a list and to stop when the age is <= 0 and find the average age. I've been struggling on how to add the user input into a list. I can't figure out which type of loop to use.

```
age = int(input("Please enter an age (or 0 to quit): "))
age_list = []
def get_ages():
    list = age.split()
    if age >= 0:
```

Comment: You can use *"any type of loop"*, as long as they are loops that iterate. I don't see a loop in your code. Have you tried to add a loop?

Comment: @crispybacon98 use `while age > 0:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a loop here,

try something like this:

```
age_list = []
while True:
    age = input("Please enter an age (or 0 to quit): ")
    if int(age) <= 0:
        break
    else:
        age_list.append(int(age))
print(str(sum(age_list) / len(age_list)))
```

also, welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to iterate forever until a 0 or negative number is input. Something like this should work:

```
age_list = []
while True:
    age = int(input("Please enter an age (or 0 to quit): "))
    if age <= 0:
        # this will break out of the loop
        break
    else:
        age_list.append(age)
    
print(age_list)
```

Comment: A while loop is a great way to solve this problem. I'd probably write `while True:`, as that is slightly more readable than `while(1==1):`. But either way of writing it gives the same result. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function, you can do it like this:

```py
def get_age():
    age_list = []  
    input_age = True  

    while input_age:
        age = int(input("Please enter an age (or 0 to quit): "))
        if age > 0:
            age_list.append(age)
        else:
            input_age = False

    return age_list

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    print(get_age())
```